# Missing yo.rc.json file

Tags: yeoman, mean-stack, meanjs, yeoman-generator

I generated a mean stack template using the mean generator

yo mean

I am trying to create submodules but it always creates the entire app again because there is no .yo.rc.json file in the folder.

yo doctor says everything is ok

Where should this .yo.rc.json be and is there a way to generate one based on the files I have in my app?

Comment: Looks like a bug with generator-mean to me. You should report the issue. Otherwise just create file manually `touch .yo-rc.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in the generator itself. I've tried other generators and they create the .yo-rc.json file. The angular full stack generator provides a similar structure if anyone encounters the same problem.